# How to delete a chat message which was saved using xep-0136(Message Archiving)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I want to provide user a functionality to delete single or multiple messages at a time using long-tap/select action.

I know you want to know what I have tried so far. But the thing is I haven't found anything regarding deleting messages to implement.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to delete message from xmpp core database.
So xmpp had created "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" named core database table and using this you can delete message.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" inManagedObjectContext:myAppdelObject.Obj_xmppManager.moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;
NSArray *items = [mocObject executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [mocObject deleteObject:managedObject];
}
```

Comment: Will definitely give a try and get back to you.

Comment: This got me half way through, I can delete message now, But each time I re-login(into app) , the deleted message appears again. How can I permanently delete message?

Comment: Sir i want to reload the TableView. i try alot but not effective.  This is the  'IMMainMessageC' Class in Which 'initWithStyle' this is the Function that work for reloading when new message. i dont know how to Reload the TableView in XMPP when any Message Delete from Tableview.Thanks for advance.

Comment: You have to get message in array from database. And after delete message  from database you have to get remaining messages in array from database and reload UITableview.

Comment: how to fetch messages from openFire with xmpp framework??

Answer (score 0):

@Parthpatel1105's answer is right, though as @Bista says, it will not delete the messages permanently.

After performing the deletion, any deletion, either full deletion as @Parthpatel1105 does, or a single message, which would be the same but without the for loop and you'd have to find the single message to delete. You HAVE to save the storage context.

Which means, after doing:

```
for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
    [mocObject deleteObject:managedObject];
}
```

You have to add a call to save,

In Swift (where I've used it):

```
mocObject.save()
```

In Objective-C, I think it would be something like:

```
[mocObject save:&error];
```